# Creating a layer of gradient within an SVG path dynamically

Tags: svg, path, mouseevent, gradient

I am creating a dynamic path using my SVG. I now wish to add gradient to my path but I am stuck. The way I am trying, my gradient is coming along the path as shown in image 2 while I require it to be the kind in image 1.

[image: Needed_Picture]

Current

[image: Current_Picture]

My gradient and stroke definitions are as follows :

```
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id = "grad1" spreadMethod="reflect">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: lightcoral;" />
            <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color: #ffffff;" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: lightcoral;" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

script :

```
svgPath.setAttribute("stroke", "url(#grad1");`
svgPath.setAttribute("fill", "none");
svgPath.setAttribute("stroke-linejoin", "round");`
svgPath.setAttribute("stroke-width", "10");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a gradient run along the stroke of a path, turning at the corners etc., if that's what you mean.

If instead you just want to make it so the gradient is oriented vertically, then you need to use the `x`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2` attributes to set the line along which the gradient runs.  If you don't specify these attributes, the gradient is oriented horizontally as per your second image.

```
<linearGradient id = "grad1" spreadMethod="reflect" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: lightcoral;" />
    <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color: #ffffff;" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: lightcoral;" />
</linearGradient>
```

If you want to have a "pipe" like gradient effect, then the simplest method is to layer multiple paths of different stroke widths.

Here's a simple example to demonstrate.

```html
<svg fill="none">
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#666" stroke-width="30"/>
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#999" stroke-width="24"/>
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="16"/>
  <polyline points="0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="6"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul LeBeau. Yes, indeed I want a pipe-like gradient effect but instead of using Polylines, I want to do it with a path. Since, its being created dynamically using the mouse in my problem, any idea as to how I can create layers within it?

Comment: Whether it is a path or a polyline doesn't matter. The coords are identical for all layers. The only difference is the stroke thickness.  That's assuming you can draw the pipe you want just with a path stroke.  Do you need a fancier pipe shape than that?

Comment: No. This would do but since the path is being drawn with the movements of my mouse, I do not know how to incorporate different stroke-width within one another. @PaulLeBeau

Comment: If you have four paths in your pipe, then you just have to update all of them when you add a point.

Comment: Okay. I am going to try that and update. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Answer @Paul LeBeau inspires, very interesting technique - immitations of the gradient along the curvilinear path.

This technique can be used to animate the movement of fluid along the pipes, filling the vessels.
I tried to make such an example of animation.

Steps to implement the animation:

- We replace the `polyline` command from the example above, with the `path` command.
- All patches that imitate the shades of the pseudo-gradient are
  assigned the same  `class="poly"`
- we animate all patches at the same time, using the attributes
  `stroke-dasharray`, `stroke-dashoffset`

```css
svg {
stroke-linejoin:round;
fill:none;
}
.poly {
stroke-dasharray: 850 850;
  stroke-dashoffset: 850;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-name: draw;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
} 

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 850;
  }

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400"> 
   <path             d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#7C7C7C" stroke-width="30" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#4E4E4E" stroke-width="30" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#5C5C5C" stroke-width="28" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#6E6E6E" stroke-width="24" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#7C7C7C" stroke-width="22" /> 
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#828282" stroke-width="20" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#8D8D8D" stroke-width="18" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#9F9F9F" stroke-width="16" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#ADADAD" stroke-width="14" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#BDBDBD" stroke-width="8" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#C5C5C5" stroke-width="6" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#D2D2D2" stroke-width="4" />
  <path class="poly" d="M0,125, 150,125 150,25, 300,25 300,175 0,175" stroke="#D6D6D6" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```